# It is OK to use STI in this situation?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inheritance, sti

I have a table named `people`
Each `person` can be a `client`, a `manager`, an `accountant`, or any combination of the three.
Also each of them have special table columns, besides the ones in the `people` table.

What I'm doing now is using a `person_id` in each of the tables... but I think it would be much simpler to just used the same table, and a different model for each one, so I can manage them separately.

Should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a nice inheritance hierarchy so I don't think STI applies. For example, how would you represent a person that was both a manager and an accountant in terms of (single) inheritance?

If a person could only have one of the three roles then maybe STI would make sense; but even then implementing roles using inheritance should be setting off warning bells in your head, you should know that one person will end up needing multiple roles sooner or later (and it will probably become a critical necessity immediately after delivery).

Comment: I'm using flags in the table and a default_scope: `t.boolean :is_client` and `default_scope where(is_client: true)` and then:
    `def destroy;
      if not new_record?;
        update_attribute :is_client, false;
      end;
      freeze;
    end`